# Venue/Indoor Map using D3.js and Geojson

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I have created geojson file which contains all the features of 1st floor of a shopping mall. I got that venue map projected using d3.js with different colors but only some parts not the complete map. Below is the script code and link to the geojson file. Also please note that i have not converted this geojson into topojson and used Qgis to draw the maps and c#.net to convert the geometry data to geojson objects. Can anyone please check my json and my d3.js code? Do I need to use any other projections?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pu2s0yamfkd89p/JSONfromDB_8Feb2014.json

```
 $(document).ready(function () {                       
      parseResultShopDetails();                     
 });

 function parseResultShopDetails() {

    var width = 600, height = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
               .scale(30)
               .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
                        .projection(projection);            

      d3.json("http://localhost:1209/data/JSONfromDB_8Feb2014.json", function (error,       jsonData) {
        var color1 = d3.scale.category10();

        svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(jsonData.features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("d", path)
                        .attr("text", function (d, i) { return "js"; })
                        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color1(i); });


    });           
}
```

Comment: You're generating a lot of NaN's.  I'm not sure about your coordinates, they seem to be too large for the Mercator (or any) projection.  I wouldn't think that using earth projections would be the best for the design of shopping mall.  Can you use a local coordinate system.  This [conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/OSp_sMZjfok) on gg might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the d3 mapping tools really fall apart if you try to use coordinates other than longitude and latitude.

I tried creating a "null" projection that just returns the input values, but the negative numbers and numbers greater than 360 were still getting wrapped by d3 before passing to the projection function.  That avoids the trig errors from the Mercator projection, and it creates interesting art, but not the floor plan you were hoping for:

```
var projection = d3.geo.projection(function(λ, φ) {
  return [ λ, φ ];
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rR2hG/1/

However, all is not lost.  The second image in that example is created by just passing the array of coordinates as the points of `<polygon>` elements.  I think that's closer to what you wanted.  So you'll need to do a little more work to grab the points from the data file but you can definitely visualize them just as an array of coordinates.

```
    svg2.selectAll("polygon")
        .data(jsonData.features)
        .enter()
        .append("polygon")
        .attr("points", function(d){ return d3.merge(d.geometry.coordinates);})
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color1(i);
        });
```

The only other suggestion is to write a script to convert your geoJSON file to geographic units.  They don't have to be actual latitude and longitude of a particular place (you could still have the map centered on a reference point of your choice), but the scale has to be in degrees not feet or meters or whatever you are using.

Comment: Amelia, Great thanks for your help. I tried your code and got the same result. I think there should be some projection for geometry coordinates.

Comment: Hi, Can I ask you one more question why the mall image is being flipped than the original one when rendering using D3.js?

Comment: Flipped vertically?  The original coordinates probably used y=0 at the bottom of the image, but in SVG by default y=0 is the top of the image, and the coordinates increase as you move down.  If you want the reverse, you need to use a scale where the max and min values of the range (output) are in the opposite direction as the max and min of the domain (input).

Comment: Hi Amelia, Thanks for the quick reply. Could you please update the code at jsfiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/rR2hG/1/)  which you had created previously. I found out how to get the max, min but not sure where to put in that (jsfiddle) code. d3.max(d.geometry.coordinates[0], function (dt) {
                            console.log("max : " + dt[1]);
                        });

Comment: It would be easier to use a [d3 scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-quantitative); see the other answer and look at general d3 tutorials for how to use scales.

Answer (score 6):

D3's mapping projections are designed to transform 3D earth coordinates into 2D browser coordinates, so they are not that great at transforming local coordinates like the ones you've got.  And as Amelia outlines your putting in coordinates that are outside of what's expected.

You'd be better off doing one of two things; creating a geometry stream based on 2 linear scales as outlined in [this google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/OSp_sMZjfok) discussion; or using d3's path generators.

To creating a 2D path generator is straightforward in d3 something like this will work:

```
var shops = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    })
```

The real trick here is accessing the 'right' part of your json object. If you look into the geojson structure you see that there is a geometry part as well as an properties part.  You need to dig through to pull out the coordinates and then pass them to the pavement generator.  In this case it would be:

```
d.geometry.coordinates
```

which would obviously need to be referenced correctly.

Note that the method outlined here isn't going to work if you have complex geometries such as multi-polygons, you'll need to do quite a bit more work.  If that's what you've got you'll want to create a custom geometry stream.

Now putting all of that together [here's a working example](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/9298880) of you're json.

Comment: Many thanks @user1614080, Your answer is very helpful to me. I will work on the solution you have provided, generate the complete map and let you know the results. Great Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Can I ask you one more question why the mall image is being flipped than the original one when rendering using D3.js?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can take a look at this thread. I have the same problem with multipolygon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359640/geojson-and-d3-js-multipolygon