# Why does my d3 map look strange?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am trying to project a d3 map of the US. For some reason, it looks like this:

[image]

I used mapshaper.org to create a topojson. I took a look at this link:

[d3 toposjon map troubleshooting … why does it look like all zig zags and shards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132342/d3-toposjon-map-troubleshooting-why-does-it-look-like-all-zig-zags-and-shards)

but it wasn't very helpful. Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var width = 960,
                height = 500;

            var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                .scale(1000)
                .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

            var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection(projection);

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            d3.json("states.json", function(error, us) {

              svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
                  .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b && !(a.id / 1000 ^ b.id / 1000); }))
                  .attr("class", "county-boundary")
                  .attr("d", path);

              svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
                  .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                  .attr("class", "state-boundary")
                  .attr("d", path);
            });

            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");                
    </script>
</body>
```

Could you help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Set `fill: none; stroke: black` for `path` elements in your CSS.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, this fixed it somewhat. However, I'm no longer getting the outline of the country: http://i.imgur.com/SHlq4t8.png Do you have any idea what? Thank you for your help!

Comment: These may be in the data as a separate object -- `us.objects.country`?

Comment: Maybe as Lars said, or you have something special in the CSS on the boundarys what could also be possible. Did you take an existing example, than please show your code.

Comment: Thanks all! I added the following code: `svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
                        .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
                        .attr("class", "land")
                        .attr("d", path);` and it added the country boundry.