# Data visualisation with custom indoor geospacial information

Tags: d3.js, visualization, geospatial

I am looking for a way to create a visualisation of live data (temp., humidity) from within a multi-story building overlaid on the floor plans. Each floor will likely be a projected iso view, laid over one-another.
I will most likely be using D3.js for the plotting, but am open to others.

I am currently considering two options:

- using a [3D plot projection](http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/5986172), and adding the floor plans as custom data.
- creating custom TopoJSON files for each floor, and using a [custom projection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6216797).

I am leaning toward the former.

Has anyone done any similar projects using purely indoor geospacial information? I can't seem to find any examples.
Any thoughts on which of the above two, and any other alternatives, will provide a more elegant or simple design?

Comment: Perhaps this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111036/venue-indoor-map-using-d3-js-and-geojson) will help answer some of these.  Be sure to follow the links in the posts.

Comment: Yes, thank you @user1614080. That covers perfectly my concerns with the projection method, and provides sample code achieving exactly what I wanted.